# Why Hard edges on icing of Donut?

Tags: modeling

[image]Following Blender guru donut tutorial, I am on the section of icing but the icing are looking somehow sharp, what could be the possible reasons and how to tackle this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is an industrial donut, or not enough subdivision in the modifier (we can't see it in the screenshot above)?

Comment: I have done the subdivision 1 time and smoothen out as well.

Comment: Try two (or if needed three) subdivs.

Comment: You see, After applying 2-3 subdivisions still it is a sharp edge

Comment: ok, could you upload the blend file? please use this link (dedicated to BSE) to do it: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have done it, please check

Comment: All seems to be ok with 1 subdiv. In edit mode, select all and use the menu "vertex > smooth vertices" with some repeats in the operator panel. Screenshot from your file https://i.stack.imgur.com/P50C2.jpg

Comment: Though, if you add an extrusion like shown in the first screenshot above, should also increase subdivision, or make it another way following edge loops

Comment: Hey, used the modifier subdivision surface and it smoothen out the edges. Btw, thankyou so much for your time and help.